# Direct connect device to ethernet port on pc, and give it internet access through my wireless

Tags: internet, wireless-networking, ethernet, bridge

Ok, bear with me this is going to be a long explanation.

I have my PC(Ethernet) and a PS2(Ethernet) connected a router(B).
My PC is also connected to my homes wireless(A) connection for the internet.

I need to find a way to give my PS2 internet access.
I have tried to make router(B) bridge to my home wireless(A). But my home router(A) is a cruddy old belkin thing, and it wont let my router(B) connect to it via router bridge. My computer wont use both connections at the same time either, I've tried computer network bridge too, in fact, then neither work.

Is it possible and if so how, can I connect my PS2 to my computers Ethernet port directly and access it as a device or IP on my computer, and give it access to my computers internet.

Any and all possible solutions would be helpful.

PS: I've made sure all of the things I've already tried were perfect, bridging is no longer an option. But if the router(B) is required in the solution then that's ok. Please note that I cannot change anything on my Family router(A)

- Playstation2
- Router(B) is a TP-Link
- Atheros 802.11 a/b/g/n Dualband Wireless Network Module (WIRELESS)
- Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller (ETHERNET)
- Windows 7

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Windows, starting from XP I think, includes a network-sharing functionnality. To activate it, go to the `Network and Sharing Center`, then select `Change adapter settings`. Here, double-click on your `Wireless connection`, then click on `Properties`, and go to the `Sharing` tab. Now tick the `Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection` box.
It'll reroute packets from the Ethernet interface to the wireless interface, and start a DHCP server which will attribute an IP adress for both the Ethernet card and the PS2. So be sure to connect directly your PS2 to your PC, and check that the Ethernet card is using automatic TCP/IP configuration.
In this setup, the router B is useless. Playstation 2 is connected by Ethernet to the PC Ethernet port, and the wireless card of the PC is connected to your wireless network (which is connected to Internet).

Answer (score -3):

Apparently this is a thing, I'm not sure?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable

Comment: An ethernet crossover cable consists of the same wiring as a typical ethernet cable; the difference is only in which order the wires are clamped into the connectors.  [Wiring diagram](http://i.stack.imgur.com/63Ry5.png)